# Alternate an image while it's moving in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have this image in Pygame which moves around the screen. What I want to do is alternate every other time. So, I want it to start off as image1.png and then move across the page, switching between human1.png and human2.png and finish up back on image1.png. Is this possible?

My code is:

```
if (human1_position.left <= 555):
    human1_position = human1_position.move(2, 0)  # move first human
    pygame.display.update()
else:
    move = STOP
screen.blit(human1, human1_position)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
# Before main loop
human_files = ["human1.png", "human2.png"]
human_sprites = [pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha() for filename in human_files]
human1_index = 0

...

# During main loop
if (human1_position.left <= 555):
    human1_position = human1_position.move(2, 0)  # move first human
    human1_index = (human_index + 1) % len(human_sprites) # change sprite
else:
    move = STOP
    human1_index = 0
human1 = human_sprites[human1_index]
screen.blit(human1, human1_position)
pygame.display.update()
```

I moved the update() call, it should occur only once per frame after all has been drawn.

Comment: on the update issue. You are of course right. But if you ever want to get a decent framerate in pygame, my exp shows you have to switch to updating only the rects you changed, not the whole display (nothing to do with the original problem thogh)

Comment: @kratenko I agree. Considering you have to keep track of every updated rectangle an then call update() only once per frame. But that's a whole new problem (performance related) and perhaps samiles doesn't need this optimization.